# What's a word for a "parrot-like" person who attacks, criticizes, and postures loudly, but only from the shoulder of someone stronger, as it were?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm running into a person like this and cannot remember the term.

I imagine the archetype is common in mob-like organizations and criminal enterprise. A person who loves to join in the kicking but only when the person is victim is outnumbered, occupied, or helpless.

Somewhat like Zazu but he is a shade different (he may be right but is overexercising his authority or using it to say personal things).

Comment: I firsth thought of 'sidekick' but your definition sounds like a specific sadistic kind of sidekick and I can't think of one word for that right now.

Comment: I could peck much further, because I stood on the shoulders of giants. (With apologies to Sir Isaac.)

Answer (score 1):

Someone who runs with the pack? (In French I'd say: who howls with the wolves)

Answer (score -1):

**henchman**    [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/henchman)

> 1. A loyal and trusted follower or subordinate, especially one who engages in **unscrupulous** or criminal behavior on the leader's behalf.

Comment: Yes, but these in contrast are *able* and not just vociferous lackey-types.

Comment: btw i'm not the person downvoting yours